# How to set default and changeable values for an Angular.js form

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have a basic form set up, with bindings via angular.js. Selecting and changing values displays and updates fine when I have no default set. What I can't seem to do is set default values that can be changed.

I have a controller defined with basic values (take for example a set of radio buttons with a default value) :

```
function Contact($scope) {

    $scope.contact = 
   {
        'website'       : '.com'
    }

};
```

And my form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" ng-controller="Contact">

 <input ng-model="contact.website" value=".com" id="com" type="radio" name="website">
 <label class="radio-label" for="com">website.com</label>

 <input ng-model="contact.website" value=".fr" id="fr" type="radio" name="website">
 <label class="radio-label" for="fr">website.fr</label>

 <input ng-model="contact.website" value=".br" id="br" type="radio" name="website">
 <label class="radio-label" for="br">website.br</label>
</form>
```

Which works in setting the default value. But when I click on one of the other options, the corresponding `{{ contact.website }}` doesn't change.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you set up an example on http://jsfiddle.net or similar? From the code in your question, it looks like it should work.

Comment: I can't post full code as its for work. but this is essen @Akallebet's fiddle encompasses it and works. http://jsfiddle.net/sx3DX/4/ The only difference I can see is I haven't defined a specific 'app'. I just use <body ng-app>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've built a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sx3DX/4/) with your example and seems to work, unless I didn't understand your question

```
<div ng-app="app" >
<form action="#" method="post" ng-controller="Contact">

 <input ng-model="contact.website" value=".com" id="com" type="radio" name="website">
 <label class="radio-label" for="com">website.com</label>

 <input ng-model="contact.website" value=".fr" id="fr" type="radio" name="website">
 <label class="radio-label" for="fr">website.fr</label>

 <input ng-model="contact.website" value=".br" id="br" type="radio" name="website">
 <label class="radio-label" for="br">website.br</label>
     <p>{{contact.website}}</p>
</form>
</div>
```

See if it's what you mean...

Comment: Hmm. It does work there (that's exactly what I want). Strange. I wonder what I've done to break it then...

Comment: I rebuilt this just now and it's all working. I must have been declaring something oddly somewhere. Thanks for confirming I was on the right path!